# compare 5 rows of cells with text values and if 2 adjacent cells have my specified text it will return a specific value

Tags: excel

This is my data file.

[CallOutcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcL3c.jpg)
What I wanted to do is compare the 5 call outcomes and if subsequent cells have "softrefuse" followed by "closed", i want a return in column I.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in I2:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B2:F2,"softrefuse"),COUNTIF(B2:F2,"closed"))
```

Then copy down

This will return `TRUE` if both are in the range in any order.

If you want to only return `TRUE` on the ones where `closed` follows directly behind `softrefuse` then use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:F2,"softrefuse",C2:G2,"closed")>0
```

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.